Proving the expected correlation between draws from N probability densities is greater than zero
Let's assume there are N probability densities (f1, f2, ... fN), each of which can have any shape.
Consider two length N vectors {x1, x2} created by taking independent random draws from each probability probability density in the same order:
x1 = {random_draw(f1), random_draw(f2), ..., random_draw(fN)}
and
x2 = {random_draw(f1), random_draw(f2), ..., random_draw(fN)}.
Is there a way to prove that the expected correlation between x1 and x2 must be equal to or greater than zero, regardless of the shapes of the individual probability densities?
In other words, if we repeat the process of drawing x1 and x2 many times and calculate the correlation between them for each pair of draws, will the average correlation always be equal to or greater than zero?
Any help or guidance on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. If the statement cannot be proven in general, are there any specific conditions or assumptions under which it would hold true?

I wonder if your description is really what you intended to ask.  If by "random draws" you mean independent draws, then the answer obviously is no, practically by definition.  How could any correlation be induced between independent random variables??  And if you don't mean independent, then what do you mean?

Sorry I have tried to clarify this - does it make more sense?

That helps, thank you.  The answer depends on the densities.  There's nothing special about positive correlations, either: the expected correlation could just as well be negative.  Is there some application of this you have in mind that might help narrow the possibilities?

I am researching measurement processes, so each density represents the distribution of observed measurements you might get if you repeatedly sampled the same subject. Xi would represent a vector of observed measurements from the N subjects. While it is clear that any given correlation between X1 and X2 could be negative, I don't see how the expected correlation could be negative.

Well, the correlation--as usually calculated--depends on the very order in which you place the distributions!  If you compute a correlation coefficient of $r$ with them in one order, then with the reverse order the correlation coefficient will be $-r.$  I suspect your mathematical description of your repeated-measurement situation is not sufficiently clear or adequate for framing or answering your question.
